# After Major Revision what is the decision?

Tags: publications, peer-review

I submitted an research paper to Elsevier journal after 4 months i got major revision
i submitting my revised paper, 
After one month i receive comments from reviewers. Editor letter stated that "I am pleased to inform .....favourable reviews from reefers....Some modifications to be implemented before the manuscript is published"

I submitted my paper at the end of march but still journal status shows that "under review".

What will be the decision i expect from the journal? pls clarify.

Answer (score 1):

The status is "under review" because the editor decided to ask the reviewers to look at the paper again. Since there's no way to tell what the reviewers are going to say, there's also no way to tell what decision you can expect, either. The fact that the initial reviews were favourable means there's a good chance your paper will be accepted, but reviewers can change their minds, and there's no way to be sure.